# Problem with superscripts in limits

Tags: equations, positioning, superscripts

### Problem

My problem concerns the position of the variable `n`, specifically when used with `limits` as shown in the following output. The fragment `x \in \mathbb{C}^{n}` works as desired. but when this fragment is used in `\argmin_{x \in \mathbb{C}^{n}}`, the variable *n* has dropped. A red line is added to accentuate the drop of *n*.

### Question

How should the second instance be written so that *n* has the same relative location in both instances?

### Example

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    x \in \mathbb{C}^{n}, \quad \argmin_{x \in \mathbb{C}^{n}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: red line]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force "uncramped" style by placing `\mathbb{C}^{n}` in `scriptstyle` (even though it already is).

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    x \in \mathbb{C}^{n}, \quad \argmin\limits_{x \in {\scriptstyle\mathbb{C}^{n}}}%
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]